# JOIN results give duplicate rows - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am currently dealing with a database that is not set up the way i think it should be. There are barely any primary/foreign keys so joining tables can be quite tricky.

I have tried to recreate a similar issue to the one i have where joins that i create result in incorrect duplicate rows which is a result of the lack of keys.

sql fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff59ad/1

Query:

```
SELECT I.InvoiceNumber, I.AmountPaid,
O.Amount
FROM OrderInvoice O
JOIN Invoice I 
ON O.InvoiceNumber = I.InvoiceNumber
```

Now as you can see there is duplicate entrys for invoice number

```
InvoiceNumber   AmountPaid  Amount
    123           10          8
    123           10          2
    567           10          4
    567           10          6
```

The total amount paid should just be 10 for each whereas the join creates 20 for each because of the matching rows. So if i group these results and sum them the total amount is wrong. Its slightly different from my real life example as it looks like i am actually getting a cross join even with normal join syntax because of the duplicated rows.

Whats the best way to remove these duplicated rows? I have tried joining on multiple columns to create a unique row but i have no other columns to join on.

Can anyone give me advice?

Comment: how the total amount would be wrong if you sum by group them ??

Comment: No that's completely normal - if you join a single 'header' record to multiple 'child' records, the 'header' record is represented against each child record. That's a completely normal join operation, and a completely normal outcome for a invoice header joining to multiple invoice lines. What are you actually trying to do here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `group by` clause with `sum` aggregation function

```
SELECT I.InvoiceNumber, I.AmountPaid,
sum(O.Amount) Amount
FROM OrderInvoice O
JOIN Invoice I 
ON O.InvoiceNumber = I.InvoiceNumber group by I.InvoiceNumber, I.AmountPaid
```

Result :

```
InvoiceNumber   AmountPaid  Amount
123             10          10
567             10          10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT I.InvoiceNumber, I.AmountPaid
FROM OrderInvoice O
JOIN Invoice I 
ON O.InvoiceNumber = I.InvoiceNumber
```

You have more then one record per `InvoiceNumber` in the second table - that's why you are getting multiple records in the final set.

Answer (score 0):

When you join `table a` to `table b` you will get one row for in your result for every match.

Io if `table b` has two rows that match `table a` then the data from table a will be duplicated. once for the first match and once for the second match.

in your case there are two rows in the `OrderInvoice` table that match one row in the `Invoice` table. the `AmountPaid` is from the `Invoice` table so it will be duplicated as the single row in `Invoice` match two rows in `OrderInvoice`.

Answer (score 0):

If the amount paid is static across all rows then you need to group by that as well, not sum by it.

```
SELECT I.InvoiceNumber, I.AmountPaid, SUM(O.Amount)
FROM OrderInvoice O
JOIN Invoice I ON O.InvoiceNumber = I.InvoiceNumber
GROUP BY I.InvoiceNumber, I.AmountPaid
```

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to be like this, 'cause you have different amount values

If you `SUM` the amounts should be ok

```
SELECT I.InvoiceNumber, I.AmountPaid,
SUM(O.Amount)
FROM OrderInvoice O
JOIN Invoice I 
ON O.InvoiceNumber = I.InvoiceNumber
GROUP BY I.InvoiceNumber,I.AmountPaid
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that maybe you're after this:

```
SELECT 
I.InvoiceNumber, 
I.AmountPaid,
L.LineTotal
FROM Invoice O
JOIN 
(
SELECT O.InvoiceNumber, SUM(O.Amount) As LineTotal
FROM OrderInvoice O
GROUP BY O.InvoiceNumber
) As L
ON L.InvoiceNumber = I.InvoiceNumber
```

This pre-aggregates the lines into a single row per invoice number with a total, then joins it to the header.

This gives you a header level figure.

If you want a line level figure you need to work out what to do with the total
 - put it on the first line?
 - put it on the last line?
 - divide it over the line?

None of these really make any sense though