# Microsoft SQL Server : join 11 million duplicate issues without using group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I do few join operation on Microsoft SQL Server, main table which is in first select has total 600k records but joins insert 11 million records into the database which is overkill. I checked other posts but still couldn't figure out how to set up correct query, I am a little bit too new to this.

I tried grouping by id for each table, also tried doing same in python thought could give any difference.

```
DECLARE @maxVal BIGINT

SELECT @maxVal = ISNULL(MAX(general_id), 1) 
FROM dbo.Sales_SS

DECLARE @Sales AS TABLE 
                  (
                      general_id BIGINT, 
                      debit_acc NVARCHAR(MAX), 
                      credit_acc NVARCHAR(MAX), 
                      date DATETIME, 
                      doc_id BIGINT, 
                      prod_id BIGINT, 
                      p_id BIGINT,
                      amount FLOAT, 
                      price FLOAT,
                      self_cost FLOAT, 
                      product_id BIGINT, 
                      code NVARCHAR(MAX), 
                      name NVARCHAR(MAX)
                 )

INSERT INTO @Sales 
    SELECT * 
    FROM 
        (SELECT general_id, debit_acc, credit_acc FROM doc.Entries) e
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT tdate as date, id as doc_id FROM doc.GeneralDocs) docs ON docs.doc_id = e.general_id AND docs.doc_id > @maxVal
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT 
             general_id as prod_id, product_id as p_id, amount, price, self_cost 
         FROM
             doc.ProductsFlow) prods ON prods.prod_id = e.general_id AND prods.prod_id > @maxVal
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT id as product_id, code, name FROM book.Products) codes ON codes.product_id = prods.p_id
    WHERE
        debit_acc = '7210' 
        AND credit_acc = '1610' 
        AND general_id > @maxVal 
    ORDER BY 
        e.general_id ASC

INSERT INTO dbo.Sales_SS(general_id, date, amount, price, cost, product_id, code, name)
    SELECT general_id, date, amount, price, self_cost, product_id, code, name 
    FROM @Sales
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JOIN results give duplicate rows - SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47156724/join-results-give-duplicate-rows-sql-server)

Comment: How to solve that? grouping didnt work

Comment: I would **strongly recommend** to use another datatype for your `amount` and `price` columns - `FLOAT` is notoriously susceptible to rounding errors - if you're dealing with precise values, especially with monetary values, I'd go with  `DECIMAL(p,s)` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT DISTINCT general_id solved everything

Comment: Not a "solution". If you've turned 600k Rows into 11 million, you have a Cartesian product somewhere; a join that is not completely specified to make only the wanted connections between rows. Fix the join issue, don't just put the database to even more work taking out 10.4 million duplicates after a faulty sql join setup caused it to put them in

Comment: nah not removing duplicates but instead making join with unique rows because found out that first table had many duplicates which was causing miltiplication of data

Comment: Good call, though it may still be possible to reduce the duplicates from that table by where clause or similar. It massively depends on the data itself. If it's true pure duplication of every column then there is probably little choice except to distinct(other than to fix up the data modelling rules so duplicates can't creep in in the first place). If there's a business rule that applies to other data that you aren't selecting, always seek to implement the same rule (such as "there's a date column that defines the latest row, some rows are only unique because of it, use it to choose one row"